# Not Exposing Google API Key in Chrome Extensions

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, google-chrome-extension, google-api

I am using a Google API that requires an API_KEY passed in as a parameter in the POST request. I've read several options to unexpose the key such as hosting it on an external server. I was wondering if there was any ways of restricting the key usage in Google Cloud Platforms to eventually only the IP Addresses of Google Chrome Extension servers, or something of this sort. Does anyone know if restricting use through IP or website domain is a feasible option? Thanks!

Comment: There's no way. The request is made by an extension from the user's device and not from Google's.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the usage of your API Key to a certain chrome extension or websites, depending on from where you are making that request

**In case of popup.js** :

The request will have an `Origin` header of `chrome-extension://<your-extension-id>`.

**In case of contentscript.js** :

The request will have the `Origin` of the current website opened, (e.g. if you are making extension for youtube, the `Origin` would be `https://www.youtube.com`)

You can then go to Google Cloud Console and set an application restriction for your API Key, choose website restriction and add the right `Origin/s`.